# The type of random number generator in cuRAND kernels

Tags: cuda, curand

A typical example of random number generation in CUDA or pyCUDA is reported in the question [How to generate random number inside pyCUDA kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169633/how-to-generate-random-number-inside-pycuda-kernel), namely

```
#include <curand_kernel.h>

const int nstates = %(NGENERATORS)s;
__device__ curandState_t* states[nstates];

__global__ void initkernel(int seed)
{
    int tidx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tidx < nstates) {
        curandState_t* s = new curandState_t;
        if (s != 0) {
            curand_init(seed, tidx, 0, s);
        }

        states[tidx] = s;
    }
}

__global__ void randfillkernel(float *values, int N)
{
    int tidx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tidx < nstates) {
        curandState_t s = *states[tidx];
        for(int i=tidx; i < N; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
            values[i] = curand_uniform(&s);
        }
        *states[tidx] = s;
    }
}
```

Using this classical example, what is the random number generator that is activated (`XORWOW`, `MTGP32`, others)?

How is it possible to change the random number generator from within the kernel?

Comment: It is fully documented in the cuRand device API documentation

Comment: @talonmies According to my understanding, to force `cuRAND` to use `Philox_4x32_10` generator, it would be enough to change `curandState_t` in the example above with `curandStatePhilox4_32_10_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default generator in the curand device API is XORWOW, as defined by

```
typedef struct curandStateXORWOW curandState_t;
```

in the device API header. You can change to another generator by substituting another state type to the `curandInit` call. Note that some generators require different arguments to the `curandInit` routine compared to the default.